# typescript: what is the difference between import and var

Tags: typescript

I have two files in the same folder:

/src/routes/file1.ts

/src/routes/file2.ts

file1.ts

```
function greet(name: srting){
   return 'Hello +' name
} 

export = greet;
```

file2.ts (**references file1**)

```
var f2 = require('./file1');

function another_greeting(name: string)
{
    return f1.greet(name) + name;
}  

exports f2;
```

This configuration works, no problem. But if in file2 I point to file1 this way

```
import f1 = require('./file1')
```

the compiler complaints with error: **Cannot find module './file1'**
This prompts me to ask: what is the difference between importing an external file with the "import" statement and the "var" statement?

Comment: More on this : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Answer (score 2):

The basic difference is that when you use `import` then TypeScript compiler (TSC) *checks* if the file `./file1` can be found by based on TypeScript compiler configuration (I mean mainly `--module` [flag](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler%20Options))! If you use only `var f2 = require('./file1');` then TypeScript does no such checking.

You can see from tests how is the keyword `import` transpiled by TSC for `commonjs` modules and for `AMD` modules:

**CommonJS:** https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/tests/baselines/reference/commonjsSafeImport.js

**AMD:** https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/tests/baselines/reference/amdImportNotAsPrimaryExpression.js

There are many other tests in [tests/baselines/reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/tests/baselines/reference) folder.

So in your case `import` should be translated to `var`.

And why does it not work? Well, the following works on my computer:

**file1.ts:**

```
function greet(name: string){
    return 'Hello ' + name;
}

export = greet;
```

**file2.ts:**

```
import f1 = require('./file1');

function another_greeting(name: string)
{
    return f1(name) + name;
}

console.log(another_greeting('test'));
```

I compile the scripts like this:

```
c:\Work\TypeScript-playground>tsc --module commonjs --target es5 file2.ts
```

and run like this:

```
c:\Work\TypeScript-playground>node file2.js
```

Comment: thank for the answer. I am using vs 2015 and after having spent few hours on this issue, for some strange reason it is working now. it looks like it must be some problems with my visual studio...

Comment: I am also struggling to successfully debug .ts files on the browser. On the server I use typescript-node-express. I can hit my breakpoints in the .ts files since the sourcemaps work well. On the browser though because the .ts files are compiled into .js first and then transformed with browserify or webpack, sourcemaps don't work and i cannot hit breakpoints in the .ts files (in chrome .js don't even appear on the devtools source tab). Have you been able to successfully debug .ts source files client-side?

Comment: `.js` has to be always in Chrome, otherwise your TypeScript code won't even run. It may be minified or concatenated though. I would recommend to disable minification and then just add `console.log`s to the generated `.js` file. It's not that great but it's a start.

Comment: if i have to resolve to use console.log in .js files to watch the flow of the execution and i cannot do it by stepping into .ts files during debug...that for me seems to defeat the whole point of using typescript. It supposed among other things to give a certain abstraction for vanilla javascript. if i have to use the generated .js because during debug .ts files are useless then why not go with vanilla javascript in the first place?

Comment: Well, you should setup your source maps in the first place. What I said is just a last resort. However, my debugging scenario is that I have compiled ts -> js files and I debug JS files in Chrome (with break points or with `console.log` in my TypeScript files) because it gives me power over the result. It works for me great and I can debug things very quickly. Moreover, you actually know what is *really* going on because `for-of` is transpiled differently for ES5 and ES6. But it's just my preference.

Comment: And also TypeScript goals are https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to debug my .ts file in chrome, hitting normally mt breakpoints inside .ts file by following this suggestion [How can I debug modular TypeScript with source maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500322/how-can-i-debug-modular-typescript-with-source-maps?rq=1) and it is working really well. It sad to see that microsoft has not provided proper tool for debugging their own technology while google is able to do that.